# modifying text in Editable Pdf files

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, pdf-manipulation

I am working on a project and I need to insert data into specified fields in an **editabble pdf** file using a C# program.
I am not very familiar with **editable pdf files** and programatically modifing field data using C#.

Does anyone know of any C# open-source APIs available in .net for filling Editable pdf files?

thanks

nRk

Answer (score 1):

[iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) is a .NET library that among other features allows you to [fill](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/PdfGenerator_CS06162007023347AM/PdfGenerator_CS.aspx) pdf forms.

Answer (score 1):

I think editable pdf files means form data pdf.
For this, you need to use Adobe FDF toolkit.
See following:
http://redgoose.ca/blog/adobe-fdf-tookit-with-c-net